# Changing Person Account RecordType to Business Account RecordType

Tags: apex, data-loader, account, person-accounts

I am investigating possibilities for changing the RecordType of an Account from Person to Business Account. The reasoning for this is that I have a third party system which syncs Accounts with Salesforce and Accounts can be created in both systems, sometimes these are created with the wrong Recordtype (or it might be that they change).

I am doing this change through [Dell Boomi](http://www.boomi.com/) and have successfully manage to do it for the change in RecordType from Busienss to Person Account types. I am not looking for a solution to this in Boomi, but what I need is some clarifications about the possibilities to acctually do it.

My investigation gives me very little to stand on regarding this, and the little information I see suggests that I might even be required to create a new Person Account and then re-referencing everything from the old Business Account to the new Person Account.

Is there another solution to this problem than doing this re-creation so to say? Any help is appreciated, APEX, DataLoader etc.

Comment: So you want to achieve a functionality where a change in record type in one system is reflected equally in the other?

Comment: The two systems makes an upsert to the other system so to say. And here they have the possibility to change the recordType, all I need to know is if it is possible to change the recordType from Person Account to Business Account in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this, also from boomi. You can change the record type, but in that update call, there should be no other fields updated.

Comment: So I should be able to simply change the RecordTypeId of the Business Account to a Person Account RecordTypeId in my first update call, and then once the RecordType is changed I should be able to do the rest of the updates. And there is no need to utilize any Contact Object or similar?

Comment: You shouldn't need a contact record in this direction. There will be one in the resulting data though, you may still want to clean that up with a separate process branch in boomi.

Comment: I splitted up the update call and it seems to work as intended, I was confused by the documentation I found for this particular change of RecordType but it seems like two update calls works good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apex Dataloader to change the RecordType.
Here are the steps:
1. Use Apex Dataloader to **Export** all the Account records. Make sure you include the **Account ID** and **RecordTypeId** while exporting.
2. Get the Record Type ID of Business Account RecordType by going to Setup-->Customize-->Accounts-->Record Types. Click on the record type and copy the 15 digit ID from the URL.
3. In the exported CSV file, replace the IDs in the RecordTypeId Column with the new ID.
4. Update the Account records by using the Dataloader and map the columns accordingly