# Separate Person Account into Business Account + Contact in Summer 15

Tags: person-accounts

I tried to separate person account by changing record type from person account to business account as advised in this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77938/changing-person-account-recordtype-to-business-account-recordtype):

```
final Account acc = [SELECT Id, recordtypeid FROM Account where id = '001c000000o9d17' LIMIT 1];
acc.recordtypeid = '012D00000006gD2';
update acc;
```

`001c000000o9d17` is a person account, and `012D00000006gD2` is a business account record type. I've got the following error:

```
 first error: INVALID_PERSON_ACCOUNT_OPERATION, person-account cannot be separated.: []
```

I remember that change of record type worked in previous releases, but it doesn't work in a newly created Sandbox (with Summer 15 release). Googling "person-account cannot be separated" doesn't help a lot (seems like it is either a newly introduced error message, or nobody faced it before).

Is "person-account cannot be separated" error a Summer 15 new feature?

Comment: Are there any field updates happening via workflow rules? If so try disabling them. I read once that the record type change operation could not be done with any other type of field update

Comment: I've checked - no workflow rules in the system